# Expected ‘;’ before ‘:’ token

Tags: c, gcc, switch-statement

I've simplified my problem and am still stumped. I am compiling the code below with:

`cc -c test.c -g`

Although `gcc` does the same. The code in `test.c` is:

```
set_nds(value)
int value;
{
    int val;
    int one,zero;

    val = 1;
    switch(val)
        {
        1:
            one = 1;
            break;
        }

    return(1);
}
```

I get the error:

```
> gcc -c test.c -g

test.c: In function ‘set_nds’:
test.c:11:4: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘:’ token
   1:
    ^
```

I must be doing something stupid, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Need `case 1:`, not `1:`.

Comment: Where is `case`? `switch` really misses his friends.

Comment: Why are you using K&R-style function definitions? Those are totally obsolete. Use a correct function prototype.

Comment: Found it; it was stupid! I was missing the "case" token that is necessary in front of the constants used to determine which case. Please ignore.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of things in your code you can fix.

First, your function definition, you should be defining the argument type within the `( )` instead and also include the return type.

```
int set_nds(int value){
    // and so forth...
}
```

Second, `switch` statements need a `case` keyword in them:

```
switch(val){
    case 1:
        one = 1;
        break;
}
// and so forth...
```

Comment: Is one `case` really enough to justify a `switch` at all?  Why not just use a more compact `if` conditional instead?

Comment: @syb0rg OP mentioned it was a simplified version of his code, who knows how many cases he actually has.